# Контроль доступа в Symfony/

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, symfony3

Здравствуйте.

Доступ к опеределенным путям задается в security.yml  или с помощью аннотаций над методами контроллера.
Можно ли как то в самом бандле определить правила доступа в формате yml или нужно делать свой обработчик (AccessDeniedHandler) на php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно только аннотациями или в `security.yml` прописать пути в `access_control`

```
 access_control:
    # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Задавать конфигурации в своём yml файле возможности нет